# Using the Option key properly on Mac terminal

Tags: mac, keyboard, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to know how to configure the <kbd>⌥</kbd> (Option or Alt) key on my Mac terminal. For example, to make <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> delete an entire word or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> move to a previous word.

If I check the box 'Use option as meta key' in System Preferences, I get those functionalities, but then I lose all other shortcuts/combinations that use the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key, such as the vertical bar character (<kbd>|</kbd>), which is very important for pipe.

I fixed one of my problems by adding the command `\033b` for the <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and `\033[1;5C` for the <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, but it seems not to work with <kbd>delete</kbd>...

Can anyone help me? I haven't seen anything satisfying around here...

Comment: What do you mean by "alt" key? What kind of keyboard do you use with what system?

Comment: I mean this key : ⌥ on the classic OS X keyboard (I guess)

Comment: On Apple hardware the "alt" label is only printed on the key for use with a different OS. In OS X, it's never called ["alt"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_key) but always called ["option"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_key) (on many keyboards *only* labelled with the ⌥ icon, representing [the pull-out plastic card](http://www.guidebookgallery.org/extras/spotlights/lisa/photos/vcf80/) situated under the Lisa keyboard). So, OS X does not know any "alt" key.

Comment: Ok, we're talking about the same key : ⌥
I'll label it as "option" key from now

Comment: It really depends on what keyboard you have. Apple seems to keep changing their mind on what it's called. My last few UK full-sized Apple keyboards both say 'alt' as well as ⌥ I haven't had one that said Option since the late 90s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In macOS Terminal APP, just select "Use Option as Meta Key" in the preference setting, it should give what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using (much better and open source) [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) replacement for native OSX Terminal, then you can go to *Preferences* -> *Keys* and add key shortcut sending hex code `0x1b 0x08` on <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>:

[image: iTerm2 settings for Option+Delete]

Comment: Would you have the key for option+leftarrow and option+rightarrow ?